# Doctrine flush() leads to "unexpected EOF"

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am still new to Symfony and can't figure out this error.

Basically I try to remove the `byUser` from my database on the table `wish`. When the `flush()` function is executed I get the error `# unable to fetch the response from the backend: unexpected EOF`

My controller:

```php
private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

#[Route('/wish/delete/{id}', name: 'delete_wish')]
public function deleteWish(Wish $wish): Response
{
   $user = $this->getUser();
        
   $user->removeWish($wish);
   $this->entityManager->persist($wish);
   $this->entityManager->flush();

   $this->addFlash("success", "Successfully removed the wish!");

   return $this->redirectToRoute('wishlist');
}
```

From `user.php`:

```php
public function removeWish(Wish $wish): self
{
    if ($this->wishes->removeElement($wish)) {
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($wish->getByUser() === $this) {
            $wish->setByUser(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Dev server logs:

```
[2021-05-07T15:16:45.680666+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2021-05-07T15:16:45.684106+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: UPDATE wish SET by_user_id = ? WHERE id = ? [null,3] []
```

My code worked before and I did not change anything on purpose. So I am quite lost where to start looking. Would anyone have some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try edit your user entity atribute wish like this: The main is onDelete="SET NULL"

```
class User
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Wish")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="wish_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
    */
    protected $wish;
}
```

Then you can delete

```
   $this->entityManager->remove($wish);
   $this->entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: The first part is actually not needed, since it has already been added by the entity maker.

However I see my problem: i used `$user->removeWish($wish);` instead of `$this->entityManager->remove($wish);`. That fixes it, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how looks removeWish($wish); but you can try:

```
private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

#[Route('/wish/delete/{id}', name: 'delete_wish')]
public function deleteWish(Wish $wish): Response
{
   $user = $this->getUser();
        
   $this->entityManager->remove($wish);
   $this->entityManager->flush();

   $this->addFlash("success", "Successfully removed the wish!");

   return $this->redirectToRoute('wishlist');
}
```

Comment: Sadly it results in the same error :(
I also added the deleteWish function